# What it's the purpose of making the backing fields private

Tags: android, kotlin

I was following google code lab , and i have understood that backing property if useful when we want to access the "read-only" version of the property outside the class, but here both properties are private (binding and _binding) why did he use backing property here

```
private var _binding: FragmentAddItemBinding? = null

private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

Comment: I am too not quite sold by the view binding sample code provided in the android documentation. I think because the binding object can subject to change during different lifecycles, but having a forced non-null field can simplify coding. I personally just use a single nullable field and just use optional chaining or null checking every time when I need to use it.

Comment: Oh, right, i didn't think of it that way, it's indeed making the code simpler, thanks alot

Comment: but doesn't the doc code produce null pointer exception, asserting the binding object isn't null?

Comment: Yes. It relies on you not to access the binding object when it is null. Specifically speaking, the binding object is set when view created, and  unset when view destroyed. You typically do not access the UI when view has been destroyed. When you do, it is a logic error you have to fix.

Comment: I personally would never use double-bang to trade reliability for convenience in any case. I treat force unwrapping just for compatibility with Java code. I would not use it when writing pure Kotlin, because compiler null checking is one of the beauty and selling point of Kotlin over Java.

Comment: Yes i actually still have a problem understanding why would we need the double-bang, but i think there are cases where we prefer to catch the exception or maybe for testing purpose when we prefer the application to crash :/

Comment: You can replace the double bang here with `?: error(“Cannot access binding while fragment is detached”)` if you want a more explicit error. Depending on the situation it might be preferable to throw some kind of exception rather than using null-safe calls and silently failing.

Comment: Yes, it's also a useful technique indeed, thanks alot